# How to play encrypted hls stream in gstreamer

Tags: ios, encryption, gstreamer, http-live-streaming

I want to realize a player on iOS in order to play encrypted hls streams. For now I can only play normal hls streams with the pipeline of `uridecodebin` or `hlsdemux`. But when I play an encrypted stream, I always get error message : "Could not determine type of stream".

I have checked on the internet but haven't found anything helpful. I found this message is from hlsdemux.c, but I cannot find it in iPhone.sdk. I use the version 1.6.4 with dev environnement Xcode 7.3 and iOS 9.3.1. I really hope someone could help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: found some [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=704555) which was talking about hls being encrypted, hlsdemux itself does not have any parameters regarding decryption .. so I am not sure how is this working..

Comment: @otopolsky yes hlsdemux has no property concerning decryption but [here](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/gstreamer-commits/2014-August/081573.html), it seems support. Although, I have no idea.

Comment: maybe its some different kind of encryption.. try asking on gstreamer IRC or opening bug report on mentioned bugzilla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asked those guys of gstreamer, for the time being, there is only two solutions for my problem.

1. modify the source code of gstsouphttpsrc.c, like the default value of `ssl-strict`
2. use a certificate signed by CA instead of a certificate self-signed

I tried the second solution, now it works.

Comment: And I think later, they will fix this bug like adding some properties to easily control the certificate.